# Broadcast items looted in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

How do I enable displaying items that I or a friend have looted in chat? I had this feature enabled once, but somehow it got disabled by itself.

I've already tried Esc > Options > Social / Chat / Gameplay

Comment: check if you are actually following "ALL" messages in the chat and not only "Party" or whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens automatically within your clan. Any legendary items identified by you or your clan-mates will be announced to the entire clan.

There is no other way to enable item announcements than to join the same clan as your friend.

Comment: but it doesn't appear in clan chat and i've got my own clan

Comment: @Rafau Only legendary items or sets do broadcast at the moment you identify them. Anything else does not.

Comment: @Rafau It doesn't show in the chat all the time for some reason but it will always be in the news section of the clan.

Answer (score 0):

I had to note that there is another annoying set of messages that you will notice once you join a Clan. Joining a Clan is a great thing to do, Clan members will usually help you out with many things to help you start understanding the game and even help level up your new characters and stuff. Unfortunately, you will notice that you are getting notifications of all your other Clan members Legendary and Set piece item drops. This is cool at first to see just how many people in your Clan are actually playing and if you are in a good Clan there should be several messages of these types. However, these messages will get annoying fairly quick, well here is some good news here's how to turn these messages off:

1. When D3 is running press the "N" key to open up your Clan page.
2. At the top of the page click on the News tab.
3. Just above the scrolling slide there is a small gear or cog symbol, click on this and it will allow you to choose what Clan messages will show up in your chat box.

I hope this information helped you out, have fun destroying the forces of evil in D3.